# EthersJS Polygon Mainnet Underpriced Transaction

Tags: ethers.js, polygon

I'm trying to do a transaction using EthersJS on Polygon Mainnet, I don't override the gas price.
According to this: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2439
I believe that EthersJS should automatically be using `maxFeePerGas`. I'm calling `feeData()` to see what it returns and `maxFeePerGas` looks good but `maxPriorityFeePerGas` is `1.5` so I don't know if EthersJS is trying to use that under the hood and can't really find how that part of the code works. `Signer.gasGasPrice()` also returns something similiar to `feeData().maxFeePerGas`.

I know I can override the code and pass my `gasPrice` by calling `feeData()` and using `maxFeePerGas` but wanted to understand why this might be happening.

I'd previously been using Ethereum testnets for the contract and it's the first time I'm using this on Polygon mainnet.

EthersJS version: `"ethers": "^5.6.9"`

Thank you